# Zeit : Prisma 2 did not initialize yet error

Tags: svelte, prisma, vercel, sapper, svelte-3

I'm using prisma 2 client with zeit for developing a sapper app. Everything works fine in my local but when tried to deploy on zeit, majority of the times it will fail and magically it works sometimes. Not really sure if there should be some configuration changes that I have to do.

```
Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma2 generate" and try to import it again.
```

I saw some similar problem with zeit here but that did not work in my case. https://github.com/prisma/prisma-client-js/issues/390

Need help please.

Comment: Which version of Prisma are you running? I would try first updating Prisma to `2.0.0-preview021`. Besides that, could you share any `postinstall` scripts you may have in your `package.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to the way that Zeit caches the `node_modules`.

Prisma generates the client in the `@prisma/client` module found in `node_modules` and if it isn't generated it throws the error that you see.

Two solutions:

- Upgrade Prisma to 2.0.0-preview021 which has a fix for this
- Add a `postinstall` script in your `package.json` with `prisma2 generate`

The latter isn't strictly necessary if you're using the latest version.